# Решение простоейшей задаче на с++

Tags: c++

**Задача.** Очень часто для работы со строками нам нужно сначала вычислить длину строки. Для C-style строк длина нигде явно не хранится, но её можно вычислить. Напишите функцию, которая вычисляет длину C-style строки. Учтите, что завершающий нулевой символ считать не нужно.

Требования к реализации: при выполнении этого задания вы можете создавать любые вспомогательные функции. Вводить или выводить что-либо не нужно. Реализовывать функцию main не нужно.

**Решение.**

```
unsigned strlen(const char *str)
{
    if(*str)
      return 1 + strlen(++str);
    else 
      return 0;
}
```

**Вопросу у меня такой** - Для чего нужна единица? Понимаю что идет рекурсия, но зачем нам складывать с единицей?
  Также если будет у кого-то другой способ решения, буду рад узнать.

Начинающий в плюсах, так что прошу сторого не ссудить

Comment: Восхитился... Это ж надо такое замутить :) Так что даже подскажу - смысл тут, что длина строки на 1 больше длины строки без первого символа, вот она отсюда... Только вот совет - не пытайтесь длинных строк длину так искать.

Comment: Длина строки равна длине той же строки, если начинать считать длину со второй буквы, плюс `1`. Вот отсюда и единица :)

Comment: Потому что, если *str не нулевой символ, значит это другой символ, значит один символ уже посчитали и нужно переходить к другому.

Comment: Использование имен стандартных функций для своих целей может приводить к неожиданным сюрпризам.

Comment: @Anton, первый символ проверили, потом вызываем функцию для остальной части строки, второй проверили, вызываем функцию для строки начиная с третьего и так, пока функция не вернет 0. Когда вернет ноль, возвратится 1(функция закончит свою работу), и рекурсивно этот 1 станет 2 (благодаря тому, что добавили 1 в каждом вызове)и т.д. до  количества символов в строке

Comment: Что значит "не считаем"? Ваша единица - это как раз и есть подсчет первого символа.

Answer (score 2):

Суть подобного (рекурсивного) решения в том, что мы не знаем длину всей строки, однако мы можем взять подстроку длиной на 1 меньше и вернуть 1 + функция, т.е. мы повторяем эту операцию, пока нашу подстроку будет куда уменьшать (длина подстроки - 1 != 0), параллельно добавляя в рекурсивную лестницу 1 (я стараюсь объяснить как можно понятнее, возможны неточности). Потом, когда выполняется крайний случай, функция собирает все эти единицы по стэку и получается 1 + 1 + 1 + 1.... Вот и все. Таким же образом с помощью рекурсии можно найти количество членов последовательности.